# React Router Doesnot Update View on Clicking the link , but after refreshing it updates

Tags: reactjs, react-router

It All did fine until I used the Link. It can be manually accessed through url but, when accessing through links , it updates the url but doesnot update the view.

````
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../logo.png';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


export default class Navbar extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light px-sm-5">
           <Router>
            <Link exact to="/">
<img src={logo} alt="store" className="navbar-brand"/>```Links```
            </Link>
            </Router>
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item ml-5">
                   <Router> <Link exact to="/" className="nav-link">
                        Templates
                    </Link></Router>   
                </li>
            </ul>
            <Router> <Link to="/Cart" className="nav-link">
                        <i class="fas fa-cart-plus">Checkout</i>
                    </Link></Router>
        </nav>
      )
   }
 }
````

Comment: You only need a single `Router` to wrap the entire application. As long as `Navbar` is wrapped with `Router`, you can use `Link` without wrapping each `Link` with an extra `Router`. Also please update your code to show your `Route` components as you need to have `Route` components that have `path` prop match the `Link` `to` prop values.

Comment: Thank you.But Even With a single router it doesn't work

Comment: You need to share your code containing your Route components.